# Proving Binomial Coefficient Identity With $(1+x)^{2n}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

In my textbook, it asks me:

> By comparing coefficients of $x^n$ on both sides of the identity $(1+x)^n(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{2n}$, show that$$\binom {2n}0^2+\binom {2n}1^2+\binom {2n}2^2+\binom {2n}3^2+\cdots+\binom {2n}{2n}^2=\binom {2n}n$$

Why is it:

$$\binom {2n}0^2+\binom {2n}1^2+\binom {2n}2^2+\cdots+\binom {2n}{2n}^2$$

And not:

$$\binom {n}0^2+\binom n1^2+\binom n2^2+\cdots+\binom nn^2$$

This is the second one is comes from taking:

$$\binom nn\binom n0+\binom n{n-1}\binom n1+\binom n{n-2}\binom n2+\cdots+\binom n0\binom nn$$

And using the symmetry of Pascal's Triangle:

$$\binom nr=\binom n{n-r}$$

Where does the $\binom {2n}r$ come from in the textbook? Thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: This is decidedly false. For $n=1, \binom{2}{0}^2+\binom{2}{1}^2+\binom{2}{2}^2=2+\binom{2}{1}^2\ne\binom{2}{1}^2$

Comment: @Cathedral My bad, I made a mistake while copying over the $\LaTeX$ over from the image. It should be $\binom {2n}n$ on the RHS

Comment: It still is false. The actual identity *is* $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: @Cathedral Yes lol it is still false, was writing answer when you commented that

Comment: The LHS in the textbook contain $\binom{2n}{n}$ as a term and so the statement is false.

Answer (score 4):

There must be a typo in the textbook. For the case $n=1$, then

\begin{align*}
\binom {2n}0^2+\binom {2n}1^2+\cdots+\binom {2n}{2n}^2 & =\binom 20^2+\binom 21^2+\binom 22^2\\ & =1+4+1\\ & =6
\end{align*}

That, is decidedly not equal to

$$\binom {2n}n=\binom 21=2$$

The actual equation is, as you seem to have correctly proven,

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom nk^2=\binom {2n}n$$

Comment: So, I was correct? Thanks so much :)